# AspectJ annotation pointcut not triggered for interface annotations

Tags: java, spring, annotations, aspectj

How would one create a pointcut that matches methods that are annotated with an annotation or whose interface method is annotated with an annotation?

```
public interface IService {
    @SomeAnnotation
    public void someMethod() { ... }
}

public class Service implements IService {
    public void someMethod() { ... }
}
```

I'm using Spring AOP for AspectJ autoproxying. However, if I define a pointcut like

```
execution(public * *(..)) && @annotation(SomeAnnotation)
```

the advice is not applied on the someMethod method on Service.

What would be the correct pointcut to match that method, only using the fact that the interface method has an annotation on it? Is it possible?

If I put the annotation on the Service someMethod method, the above pointcut works, but in my case, this is not a good solution, as the annotation is part of the contract and must therefor be part of the interface, not the implementation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [@AspectJ pointcut for methods that override an interface method with an annotation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178782/aspectj-pointcut-for-methods-that-override-an-interface-method-with-an-annotati)

Answer (score 1):

According to the Java 5 specification, non-type annotations are not inherited, and annotations on types are only inherited if they have the @Inherited meta-annotation.

http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/annotations-pointcuts-and-advice.html#annotation-inheritance-and-pointcut-matching

Comment: This does not answer the question, since it applies to method annotations, not class annotations.

Comment: @hstoerr I think we are talking about method annotations

Comment: the question is about annotation on method, the @Inherited only works on class annotation. And not even works on interfaces!

Comment: @Hossein I never said that `@Inherited` would fix the problem, I only quoted why it does not work.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings but you what you wrote doesn't answer the question!

Comment: @Hossein yes it does. It explains why it does not work. Not every question has a positive answer.