# AOP Pointcut on the javax.ws.rs.Path Annotation defined on Interface in Java

Tags: spring, jax-rs, cxf, aspect

I am trying to apply the Before Aspect on all the JAX-RS call made in my project. I will capture All the Rest Services. When I Apply pointcut on the package level then it works fine but idea is to capture everything @Path is being referred in project from the security point of view.

AOP pass for pointcut

@Before("execution(* com.dnegi.service.*.*(..))")

I have set up Spring MVC + Apache CXF + Tomcat.

Service to Aspect:

```
    import javax.ws.rs.GET;
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
    import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
    
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    
    import com.dnegi.exception.AnimalNotFoundException;
    import com.dnegi.model.CookingInstruction;
    
    
    /**
     * JAX-RS service interface.
     * 
     * Defines our service methods annotated with the JAX-RS mappings
     * 
     * Endpoints all sit under the root Path of /cookingtime 
     * 
     */
    @Component
    @Path("/cookingtime")
    public interface CookingTimeService {
    
        /**
         * Get cooking instructions for the specified type of meat and weight passed
         * in as URL parameters, e.g. cookingtime/turkey/1.24
         *  
         * @param fleshType type of meat to cook 
         * @param fleshWeight weight of meat to cook
         * 
         * @return instructions containing the oven temperature and cooking time
         * 
         * @throws AnimalNotFoundException if the type of meat is one we don't know how to cook
         */
        @GET
        @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
        @Path("/{fleshType}/{fleshWeight}")
        @CustomAnnotation
        public CookingInstruction getCookingTime(@PathParam("fleshType") String fleshType,
                                                 @PathParam("fleshWeight") Float fleshWeight) 
                        throws AnimalNotFoundException;
    }
```

Aspect to Apply

```
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class ReadOnlyUserAspect {


      @Before("@annotation(javax.ws.rs.Path)")
        public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {

            System.out.println("logBefore() is running!");
            System.out.println("hijacked : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
            System.out.println("******");
        }
}
```

It is not being applied on the Interface but if i define the @Path in the class then annotations work fine.

Working One:

```
import javax.management.Notification;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Path("/notifications")
public class NotificationsResource {
   
    @GET
    @Path("/ping")
    public Response ping() {
        return Response.ok().entity("Service online").build();
    }


    @POST
    @Path("/post/")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response postNotification(Notification notification) {
        return Response.status(201).entity(notification).build();
    }
}
```

It seems like annotation are not inherited and because of which pointcut on annotation is not working. I created custom annotation then it worked when i used Inheritable Annotation on it. But I am still facing problem of how to make **@Path** [JAX-RS] Annotation work for my project.

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
public @interface CustomAnnotation {

}
```

Comment: Annotations are not inherited from parent class/interface.

Comment: I am creating a library so that it will provide pointcut for all the REST calls without mentioning the package. Is there someway to go about it? As i cannot change the code to include @Path on the Class level.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@AspectJ pointcut for methods that override an interface method with an annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178782/aspectj-pointcut-for-methods-that-override-an-interface-method-with-an-annotati)

Comment: @Vladmir No I guess ! as Path Annotation is provided by JAX-RS and it does not have Inherited Annotation . If this was custom Annotation than it would have worked. The link you provided is saying that there is not a way with Spring AOP !